# AJAX Codeigniter - You did not select a file to upload(error)- How to pass the file through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to upload images via an AJAX call and Codeigniter:

My View:

```
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload'); ?>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" id="upload_file_1" />
            </form>
```

My Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#upload_file_1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var filename = $("#userfile").val();
            $.ajax({
                url         :'index.php/upload/do_upload', 
                secureuri      :false,                   
                 fileElementId: 'userfile',
                dataType    : 'json',
                type : 'POST',
                done  : function (data)
                {

                    alert(data);
                }
            });               
        });
    });
});
```

and my controller:

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' '));
    }

    function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
        $config['max_width'] = '10240';
        $config['max_height'] = '7680';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {                        
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());    
            echo "error!";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($error);
            echo "<pre/>";
        } else {
            echo "done!";
        }
    }

}
```

but it gives me an error saying : "You did not select a file to upload. "; without AJAX it works fine, probably my AJAX call is not right! Could you please let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get these fields from:- `secureuri`, `fileElementId`?

Comment: Also you have to use XHR2 to upload files via Ajax.

Comment: I found them in another example! so if fileElementId is not a right choice to pass to controller what is my option to pass the file to my controller? Thanks

Comment: You have to use uploadify for uploading a file. Because you can not pass the file like this in ajax

Comment: Thanks Umair; so apart from Uplodify or any other plugins, the only way that I can use AJAX in my case is using XHR?BTW, I never knew that we cannot use AJAX for uploading file... That's interesting ...

Comment: You can use formData(HTML5) of javascript to upload files to server using ajax

Answer (score 0):

In my very recent project i used below code to upload files with formdata asynchronously using jquery ajax,
However i was not able to upload files with success: function() of jQuery so i used complete to process server response. You can try with success:function().

You will receive your data in $_Post & file in $_FILES variable.

If only want to upload files. change it like wise.

Hope this will help you.

Also look at this tutorial:http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

```
function frm_submit(){     
    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('frmSample')); //frmSample is form id
            var file = document.getElementById('userfile').files[0]; //userfile file tag id
            if (file) {
                form.append('userfile', file);
            }
        $.ajax({
                url: 'path/to/upload/script',
                type: 'POST',
                xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
               //progressHandlingFunction to hangle file progress
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                data: form,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,  //must
                processData: false,  //must
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                      console.log('complete');
                },
                error: function() {
                  console.log('error');
                }
           }).done(function() { 
                  console.log('Done Sending messages');    
            }).fail(function() {
            console.log('message sending failed');
            });
}//function frm_submit ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this javascript library
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 and got file uploading working with ajax - drag/drop + progress bars, and returns the appropriate file icon or image thumbnail that could be downloaded straight away. it was quite difficult to get it fully working and abstracted so the same routine handled multiple types of uploads each with their own restrictions.
the link will give some basic example code, it is worth a look.

pete